# slow and bugging web services for android app on server

Tags: php, android, mysql

When I'm using local host (xampp) everything is good. It's fast and without lagging, bugging and so on...
But when I use 000webhost (free) server response is too slow. Speed of retrieving 10 items with volley post (with base64 images and 7 more string values) and displaying them in list view is around 15seconds (on xampp server it's 2-3 seconds). 
Sometimes server is not responding at all or display this error:

> Error
>   SQL query: Edit Edit
>   SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';

MySQL Documentation said:

> #2006 - MySQL server has gone away

I'm gonna put some php and android code to see if I'm doing something wrong or simply free web hosting is not good.
**So, my question is: Am I doing something wrong (bad code) or I need to find some good and responsive web hosting?**

android code for getting items from web services (volley):

```
private void fillGridView(){

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        itemsArray = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = new Volley().newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        final Session session = new Session(getActivity().getApplicationContext());


        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.LOAD_DEFAULT_CITY_ITEMS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                    JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String cityName = jsonObj.getString("CityName");
                        String shopName = jsonObj.getString("ShopName");
                        String price = jsonObj.getString("Price");
                        String dateExpiring = jsonObj.getString("DateExpiring");
                        String category = jsonObj.getString("Category");
                        String image64 = jsonObj.getString("Image");
                        String location = jsonObj.getString("ShopName");
                        String username = jsonObj.getString("U_Username");


                        itemsArray.add(new SingleItem(cityName, shopName, price, dateExpiring, category, image64,
                                location, username));

                    }


                    Collections.reverse(itemsArray);


                    customGridBrowseAdapter = new CustomGridBrowseAdapter(getActivity(), itemsArray);

                    gridView.setAdapter(customGridBrowseAdapter);

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("PROFILE","Catch activated"  + e.toString());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<>();
                parameters.put("CityName", session.getDefaultCity());

                return parameters;
            }
        };

        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

php code for getting some items from mysql database:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    require 'connection.php';
    loadItems();
}

function loadItems(){

    global $conn;

    $cityName = $_POST['CityName'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM items
            WHERE CityName = '$cityName';";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $temp_array = array();

    if($number_of_rows > 0){

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $temp_array[] = $row;
        }

    }

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode(array("items" => $temp_array),  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}


?>
```

Comment: Pay for hosting then :P It's only like a few dollars a month for decent hosting.

Comment: @Farkie

Well my question is, is this a hosting problem or I'm making some mistakes :D

Comment: Very likely the hosting. I never trust free hosts... so I run my own servers :)

Comment: @Farkie 
Ok, thank you :)

Comment: Looks like you can't use stackoverflow chat else, I was going to offer :)